# hyperlink target

Tags: javascript, css, html

in HTML hyperlink, is there any way to show the second page contents in the first page?

Example:

FirstPage:

```
<a href="image1.html">image1</a> <a href="image2.html">image2</a>

<div> show image on first page here </div>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<iframe src="page.html" id="page"></iframe
<a href="new.html" target="page">Open new.html in an iframe</a>
```

You can use an iFrame.  This will create an iframe with page.html as its source, and a link that switches it to new.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [frame](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why (probably because you tagged javascript), I think you're trying to make something more like this (ajax loading in a div):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <title>Hope this helps!</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <a href="#" id="secondpage">Second Page here!</a>

     <div id="hereitgoes">
     </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  

            $('document').ready(function(){
                    $("#secondpage").click(function(){
                            $("#hereitgoes").load("secondpage.html");
                    });
            });
    });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Remember you have to run it under a web server in order to work.

Hope it helps and that it is what you intended!